# How to customize notification display and tone when using GCMReceiver and GcmListenerService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed instructions to set up an Android GCM client app [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), and have a problem specifically with this excerpt:

> For existing apps that extend a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, Google
>   recommends migrating to GCMReceiver and GcmListenerService. To
>   migrate: In the app manifest, replace your GcmBroadcastReceiver with
>   "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver", and replace the current
>   service declaration that extends IntentService to the new
>   GcmListenerService Remove the BroadcastReceiver implementation from
>   your client code Refactor the current IntentService service
>   implementation to use GcmListenerService

Most examples that I have seen for GCM implementation, use a class that extends `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.  Such as [this one](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/).  When you do that, you get the opportunity to use the `NotificationManager` and customize the notification icon, sound, etc.  However, if you follow Google's advice, I'm not sure how to customize the notifications.  Most examples that use `GcmListenerService` as suggested by Google, simply override the `onMessageReceived` method.  But that method is only called either if the application is already in the foreground when the notification is received, or when the user clicks on the notification itself.  That method isn't the right place to customize the notification sound.  The sound has already been played before that method is called.

So, if I need to customize the notification sound, I should probably override a different method in `GcmListenerService`, but there's no documentation that shows which one.  Another option is to use the `sound` attribute described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).  But then you have to bundle the sound files in the application's `res/raw` directory yourself.  That seems wrong.  I'd rather just use the system provided sounds, themes, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yet [another example](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging) which claims `GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived()` is called every time a push notification is received.  This simply hasn't been true for me (it is only called to handle push notifications if the app is in foreground).

Comment: I'm definitely missing something in my implementation.  [This](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java) sample app from Google is nearly identical.  It too implies that `onMessageReceived()` will get called every time a push notification is received, whether the app is in foreground or not.  But it still baffles me that notifications are still displayed and sound alerts are still played even if I don't override `onMessageReceived()`.  And base implementation is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@SamStern](https://github.com/samtstern) answered this question for me, when I posted it on a [Google Samples github wiki](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/166#issuecomment-183400040):

> So there are [two kinds of GCM
>   messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):
>
> Notification Messages - these are intended to generate a notification
>   with no intermediate processing by the application. They only hit
>   onMessageReceived if the app is running.
>
> Data Messages - these are intended to silently pass data to the app's
>   messaging service. They hit onMessageReceived even if the app is in
>   the background. The service may then choose to generate a notification
>   using the normal system notification APIs, or it may choose to handle
>   the message silently.

My takeaway is that if a client app wants to customize how a notification is presented to the user (i.e. change the icon in the notification tray, play a sound depending on sound settings in the app's shared preferences, etc), then we have to make the server send "Data Messages" instead of "Notification Messages".  [Here's](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java#L44-L69) the implementation in a Google Samples project, showing how to handle a Data Message.

Answer (score 0):

The option that I can only see possible is thru the payload (as you indicated) which are handled by both [XMPP](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#notification-payload-support) and [HTTP](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) connection servers. I'm not sure why it seems wrong on your part, since the server will define the `sound` data in the payload and the client will just need the file present on the respective asset folder it should be.

Display customization can also be done thru the notification payload (though its limited to `color` and `icon`)

Comment: Doesn't it seem like a lot of duplication if each app has to bundle sound files in its assets?  For instance, when I go to the Gmail app and click on account specific settings, and then on Notifications, and then Sound, I see [this](https://www.evernote.com/l/AcnKg5Pc615PWYn1EPUlj4qtXDchzFxpzrA) list of ringtones.  This is the same as the list of ringtones presented when I go to system settings.  I'm pretty sure Gmail app doesn't bundle these sound files.

Comment: To me, it sounds like Google is trying to make GCM compatible with both iOS and Android.  iOS provides no way of customizing notification tones, except via the developer bundling the sound files along with the app.