# GcmListenerService onMessageReceived called only when app is in foreground

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I have following manifest -

```
<service
    android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
    android:exported="false" />

<service
    android:name=".TestGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.test" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".RegistrationIDListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <category android:name="com.example.test" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And following `onMessageReceived` method -

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Message message;
        try {
            message = objectMapper.readValue(String.valueOf(data.get("message")), Message.class);
            MessageNotification.notify(this, message, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What happens is, `onMessageReceived` gets called only when app is in foreground. Otherwise it doesn't get called and notification is not shown. When I open the app all notifications are shown at once.

Doesn't `GcmListenereService` wake up device if locked and do the work ? How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Googled around and managed to find this thread on github which is pretty much the same as your concern, where [onMessageReceived() is only called when app is on foreground](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/166). The reason was because only **Notification Messages** are sent. As per the description included in the thread:

> **Notification Messages** - these are intended to generate a notification with no intermediate processing by the application. ***They only hit onMessageReceived if the app is running.***
>
> **Data Messages** - these are intended to silently pass data to the app's messaging service. **They hit onMessageReceived even if the app is in the background.** The service may then choose to generate a notification using the normal system notification APIs, or it may choose to handle the message silently.

I think you are sending **Notification Messages** while expecting the behavior for **Data Messages** to kick in.

Here's also the [SO post of Shiprack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35368530/6124253) mentioned in the github thread. Hope this helps. Good luck.