# Customize the push notification in android using FCM

Tags: android

I have integrated FCM push notification in my android application. And I am using FCM console for sending the notification.I am showing a customized notification when the app is in foreground because I can read the data in the `public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage`) method but the problem is I won't get data in `onMessageReceived()` method when the app is in background.

Please let me know if there is any way to customize the notification when the app is in background.

```
     if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.i("Message data payload: ", String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().toString()));

        notification_type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
        switch (notification_type){
            case "store":
                store_id = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("store_id"));
                image_url = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("url"));
                Log.i("prrr",store_id+"XCx"+String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("store_id")));
//                    message = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
                    break;
                case "product":
                    product_id = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("product_id"));
                    Log.i("prrr",product_id+"XCx"+String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("product_id")));
                    store_id = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("store_id"));
                    image_url = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("url"));
//                    message = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
                    break;
                case "category":
                    category_id = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("category_id"));
                    store_id = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("store_id"));
                    Log.i("prrr",store_id+"XCx"+String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("store_id")));
                    Log.i("prrr",category_id+"XCx"+String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("category_id")));
                    image_url = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("url"));
//                    message = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
                    category_name = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("category_name"));
                    break;

        }


    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.i("Message No: " ,"h"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    }

    sendNotification(String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData().get("url")));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: how you are triggering content from FCM ? also post your onMessageReceive()

Comment: will give the message title an in advance option will give the parameters

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257410/how-to-customize-notification-display-and-tone-when-using-gcmreceiver-and-gcmlis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue. You should be sending your notifications via your server, as a Data Message, and not through the Console.

If that's not possible, for some reason, you should check out [this tutorial.](http://codingaffairs.blogspot.co.il/2016/06/firebase-cloud-messaging-push.html)

Comment: I know that.Same time the android system will show default notification.Is there any way to customize that.Or how can I detect the data without clicking it???

Comment: How to show the notifications when the app is closed(not in bg & fg) after creating app server.Like will use broadcast receiver for GCM

Answer (score 0):

If the app is in background we won't be able to identify it from the coded for the same reason customization is not possible.