# GcmListenerService.onMessageReceived() never called

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've been looking on the internet for quite a while now, but have not found the answer.
I have followed the examples and tutorials:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

I see there are several who have problems with this when they try to send "notification" payload, but for my app, it's only "data" payload.

gcmListner:

```
public class GCMPushReceiver extends GcmListenerService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    Log.d("gcmReceiver", "something received");
    String message = data.getString("message");
    sendNotificasjon(message);

}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.premission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.myapp"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GCMPushResiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".GCMregistrationIntentService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

postman sendt:

```
{
"to":"SOME_TOLKEN_XXX",
"data": {
    "message": "melding"
}
```

}

postman received:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 73503399375464XXXX,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "message_id": "0:1471781513806225%030a2fe3f9fdXXX"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of GCM library you added?

Comment: i added com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0

Comment: Follow this guide https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start make sure you subscribe to a topic as well.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178029/gcmlistenerservice-onmessagereceived-not-called?rq=1) if it can help you.